# What's wrong with my GET request? (Commerce Services, REST)

Tags: commerce, services, 8

I'm developing a mobile app to connect with my Drupal Commerce (Kickstart) store, using a REST server.

When I do GET: `endpoint/rest/product` it retrieves the products list

```
<result is_array="true">
    <item>
        <revision_id>1</revision_id>
        <sku>TOT1-GRN-OS</sku>
        <title>Tote Bag 1</title>
        <revision_uid>1</revision_uid>
        <status>1</status>
        <log />
        <revision_timestamp>1423972403</revision_timestamp>
        <data />
        <product_id>1</product_id>
        <type>bags_cases</type>
        <language>und</language>
        <uid>1</uid>
        <created>1423972403</created>
        <changed>1423972403</changed>
        <title_field>Tote Bag 1</title_field>
        <commerce_price>
            <amount>1600</amount>
            <currency_code>EUR</currency_code>
            <data>                <components />
                </data>
        </commerce_price>
        ...
    </item>
    <item>
     ...
    </item>
```

Everything looks fine. I can even GET `endpoint/rest/product?status=1` and it does filter well.

I'm trying to filter by commerce_price.amount:

GET `endpoint/rest/product?commerce_price.amount=1600`

but it's not working. I have no problems filtering by a first level key, but can't access second level ones and so on. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, querying only works on entity properties. That is why `status` works, commerce_price is a field and won't work. Checkout [Services Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity), it may do what you're looking for.

You may still be out of luck though. You alternatives will be to use `services_views` or write your own Services Resource.

Comment: Additionally, a commerce price is a different entity type to a commerce product. Being able to query by fields wouldn't be enough for this, you'd also need the api module to resolve the entity reference as well. Be nice, but I doubt anyone's gone to those lengths

Comment: @Clive I think you're exactly right. I updated my answer to mention services_views or a custom resource right after i posted my initial answer.